# Adding text and arrow to the result of a plot

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
datacon0 = {936.1, 1203.4, 1397};
datacon3 = {733.7, 1076.9, 1202.3};
datacon6 = {788.7, 1170.4, 1298};
datacon9 = {761.2, 1142.9, 1273.8};
datacon15 = {1302.4, 1195.7, 869};
datacon18 = {1342, 1183.6, 961.4};
datacon21 = {1369.5, 1232, 1025.2};
datacon24 = {1310.1, 1192.4, 1015.3};
```

with

```
xvals = {0, 3, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24};

datacons = Symbol["datacon" <> ToString@#] & /@ xvals;

toAround = MapApply[Around]@*Map[Through@*{Mean, StandardDeviation}];

data = Transpose@{xvals, toAround@datacons};


ListLinePlot[data, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[.1]}, {0, Scaled[.1]}}, 
BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
Ticks -> {xvals, Automatic}, AxesLabel -> {"Time (h)", "cm"}, 
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", 15, GrayLevel[0]}, 
ImageSize -> Large]
```

which gives

[image]

With the help of paint (in windows), I have added text and arrow as

[image]

Can one do this directly with Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[.1]}, {0, Scaled[.1]}}, 
BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
Ticks -> {xvals, Automatic}, AxesLabel -> {"Time (h)", "cm"}, 
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", 15, GrayLevel[0]}, 
ImageSize -> Large, 
Epilog -> {Arrow[{{12, 400}, {12, 800}}], 
Text["Is It Bacteria?", {15, 600}]}]
```

There are few modifications you can make to the arrow using the modifiers you can find in the on-line manual:

```
Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[3], Arrowheads[.05], 
Arrow[{{12, 400}, {12, 800}}], Text["Is It Bacteria?", {15, 600}]}
```

Try a few combinations of thickness and arrowhead size.  Unfortunately, a hollow format arrow style is available as a textual insert, not as a graphic primitive (at least as far as I have seen).  See:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ArrowsAndArrowLikeForms.html

Your last resort would be is to draw the type of arrow you want as line segments (with scaling and positioning of the segments) and bundle it as a callable routine if you are doing a lot of graphs.

Answer (score 0):

The construction of Arrow[] is pretty simple - {{x1,y1},{x2,y2}} and {x1,y1} is the starting point for the arrow and {x2,y2} is the endpoint. The x and y coordinates are in the graph space. To move horizontally, change the x1 and x2 values to the position you desire. For example:

```
Arrow[{{5, 400}, {5, 800}}]
```

Positions the arrow at 5 on the x-axis.